# Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: '=' at line 11 column 28

Tags: apex, compile-error

```
@IsTest
private class EmailToSalesforceTests {

    // Create a new email and envelope object
    Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail();
    Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();



    // Create the email body
    email.plainTextBody = 'This should become a note';
    email.fromAddress = 'test@test.com';
    String contactEmail = 'jsmith@salesforce.com';
    email.ccAddresses = new String[] {'Jon Smith <' + contactEmail + '>'};
    email.subject = 'Dummy Account Name 123';

    EmailToSalesforce edr = new EmailToSalesforce();

    Test.startTest();
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = edr.handleInboundEmail(email, env);
    Test.stopTest();

    System.assert (result.success, 'InboundEmailResult returned a failure message');

    Account [] accDb = [select ID from Account where name=:email.subject];
    System.assertEquals (1, accDb.size(),'Account was not inserted');
    Contact [] cDb = [select firstname,lastname from Contact where email=:contactEmail];
    System.assertEquals (1, cDb.size(),'Contact was not inserted!');
    Contact c = CDb[0];
    System.assertEquals ('Jon', c.firstName);
    System.assertEquals ('Smith', c.LastName);
    Note [] nDb = [select body from Note where ParentID=:accDb[0].id];
    System.assertEquals (1,nDb.size(), 'A note should have been attached');
    System.assertEquals (email.plainTextBody, nDb[0].body);

}
```

}

Hi All, above is my code, and I am receiving the Compile Error in the title.  Any chance someone could assist me?  I can't see anything wrong with the code, considering it was provided in the Salesforce documentation.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you point out which line is line 11?

Comment: All of the code above should be within a `static testMethod void theNameOfYourMethod() {` method and not defined directly in the scope of the class itself.

Comment: The code in question is this part:                                              email.plainTextBody = 'This should become a note';
    email.fromAddress = 'test@test.com';
    String contactEmail = 'jsmith@salesforce.com';
    email.ccAddresses = new String[] {'Jon Smith <' + contactEmail + '>'};
    email.subject = 'Dummy Account Name 123';

Comment: There is a "Feedback" link at the bottom of the new documentation - if you use that to report the problem and fix (listed by Mark) you may save others this hassle in the future.

Comment: Well, the suggestion from Mark did not fix the error, I'm still getting that same issue with the unexpected token. email.plainTextBody = 'This should become a note';  ----  is that the correct code for that line?  SOmeone suggest that i change it to email.setplainTextBody('This should become a note'); -- but even when i did that, still no luck.  MARK - am I just to add the stats TestMethod void EmailtoSalesforce() to the top and close it at the bottom with another }?

Comment: see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_example.htm for a correct example of how to structure a test class and testmethod

Answer (score 1):

Please include your complete code in a method and than compile it below I have Corrected the code:

```
 @IsTest
private class EmailToSalesforceTests {

 static testmethod void TestEmailToSalesforce(){
// all your code here. Inside the test method

}
}
```

Comment: Hey Ajay... please indicate what you have changed.

Comment: I have simply put your code into a testMethod.

Comment: My code? Try again. When you answer a question, you should explain what changes you made and why in addition to any code.

Comment: I added a test method in the test class. Because Apex Code requires the creation and execution of unit tests.

Comment: So update your answer...you have a lot of code compared to your amount of explanation.